# How to add value to an existing variable, over time in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, variables, timer

For my AS level, I'm required to make a small game. What I'm trying to do is do a game similar to Cookie Clicker (http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/).

The problem that I gave is once an item is bought (that is meant to produce more muffins), I don't know how to make it add value to an existing variable(muffin in this case) over time.

This is the first chunk of my code:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim muffin As Integer

Private Property costgrandma As Integer
Private Property grandma As Integer


Private Sub Makemuffin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    muffin += 1
    LblMuffinCount.Text = muffin

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    muffin = 0
    costgrandma = 20
    grandma = 0

End Sub

Private Sub CmdGrandma_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CmdGrandma.Click

    If muffin >= costgrandma Then
        grandma += 1
        LblGrandmaCount.Text = grandma
        muffin = muffin - costgrandma
        LblMuffinCount.Text = muffin
        costgrandma = costgrandma * 1.05
        LblGrandma.Text = costgrandma

    Else
        MsgBox("Not enough muffins to pay grandma off")

    End If
End Sub
```

What I want to do is make a sub that adds a number of 'muffins' over time based on how many grandmas there are. 
For example, if you own 1 grandma, it creates another muffin automatically every second. and if there were 10 grandmas, 10 muffins would be made every second automatically.

Comment: add a timer to the form, set it to 1 sec (1000 ms) then in the Tick event make more muffins (either muffin +=1 ...or `Makemuffin.performclick`)

Comment: every second? looks like you need to use a timer....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a simple timer to do what you want every second. Check this example: http://www.techusers.net/96/example-timer-control-vbnet